# How can I compile a Java program in Eclipse without running it?

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, .class-file

I would like to compile my Java program in Eclipse but not to run it. I can't understand how to do it.

How can I compile a Java program to `.class` files in Eclipse without running it?

Comment: @TheLQ: That was right, and I didn't know that it was compiled automatically. Thanks.

Comment: Can I get compilation message also?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can un-check the build automatically in Project menu and then build by hand by type Ctrl + B, or clicking an icon the appears to the right of the printer icon.

Answer (score 12):

You will need to go to *Project->Clean...*,then build your project. This will work, even when your source code does not contain any main method to run as an executable program. The .class files will appear in the bin folder of your project, in your workspace.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on `Yourproject(in project Explorer)-->Build Project`

It will compile all files in your project and updates your build folder, all without running.

Answer (score 3):

In the case that you delete your .class file in Eclipse and then try to build it again from the .java file it will do nothing. If you try to run the .java file without the .class file you will get an error that it can not find the main class.

You will either have to change and re-save the .java file then build it again, or else you have to run Clean on the project then build again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your console:

```
javac {$PathToYourProyect}/*
```

If you also need any external library, try:

```
javac -cp {$PathToYourLibrary}.jar {$PathToYourProyect}/*
```

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the file on package Explorer
Then go to Show in
Under it go to terminal
Eclipse will have a terminal then
Use javac fileName to compile

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project explorer block ...
right click on project name
select "Build Path"-----------> "Configuration Build Path"

then the pop up window will get open.

in this pop up window you will find 4 tabs. 1)source 2) project 3)Library 4)order and export

Click on 1) Source

select the project (under which that file is present which you want to compile)

and then click on Apply

Go to the workspace location of the project (in Finder in Mac, File Explorer in Window) open a bin folder and search that class file ...

you will see the .class file which is the compiled file.

just to cross verify check the changed timing.

hope this will help.

Thanks.