# Using eclipse can not get external class folder to work (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I'm using Eclipse on a Mac. I want to write a method that creates a bar chart. To do this I need to use `Bar.java` class which I have downloaded and added as an external class folder. When I reference the class in my method it it not recognized. I have had this trouble with other classes in the past.

This is the error I receive:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Bar cannot be resolved to a type
    Bar cannot be resolved to a type

    at TaxChart.main(TaxChart.java:5)
```

`Bar.java` is in a folder located at `/Desktop/class/`
I have referenced it using *`configure build path`* and *`add external class folder`*.

Comment: Are you pointing to the folder Bar.java is in? Or the folder that Bar.class is in? (Should be Bar.class)

Comment: ..you did compile `Bar.java` into `Bar.class`, right?

Comment: sorry, i am new to java, the last time this problem occurred i then tried it on a windows machine and it worked straight away. could you tell me what i am doing wrong in a little more detail? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

External file have different package structure and hence it won't compile. Try to import that class in your project and fix compilation issues first and then try to use in your application. It should work.

Comment: i am unable to find a solution to this? could you walk be through the steps from compiling bar.java to bar.class?

Comment: It's a single source file. Copy it into your source folder.

Comment: Check this for how to compile java file to class file in eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058155/how-can-i-compile-a-java-program-in-eclipse-without-running-it