# Eclipse - build a project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project in the following structure

```
projectName
    src
       package1
         class1
       package2
         class2
```

I have enabled `build automatically` under `project` tab. It builds projects successfully and creates class files under bin.

If I disable it and do the following, it is not working

```
 right click on project --> build path --> configure build path --> source tab --> ok
```

It is not building the project. What I am doing wrongly here?

**EDIT**

yes, For the comment. I understand that I have to choose `project-->build`
But [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058155/how-can-i-compile-a-java-program-in-eclipse-without-running-it]) is confusing me.

Comment: that you're tinkering with configurations, instead of clicking the **Project** menu on the top then clicking **Build Project**...

Comment: @Downvote See my edit and look there is an answer which has two upvotes.

Comment: Nothing confusing here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23169526/2413303

Comment: Oops -- @EpicPandaForce below that one.Answered by Dipanshu

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you want to do is:

On eclipse:

```
Project --> Build project
```

**Build Project** and **Build Path** are different things.

Basically, Build Project is the compilation of your java files, and Build Path contains all of your source files and all Java libraries that are required to compile the application.

Comment: `java -cp . YourClass` <- This runs your **.class** file. Build the project means compile the code: It generates **.class** for your **.java** files. You do not run the java classes when you compile then. I guess that is your doubt. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry Man. I know what is build, deployment, pacakging. I have confused with one of the answers in SO. I tried that it is not working. So iI have posted this question

Comment: Sorry... I didn't get it at first, because your link redirects me to the question, not to the answer. Now I get it but I don't think that works. Sorry for not understanding before.

Answer (score 1):

click on  project --> build automatically (check box) for permanent code changes will build automatically.
Else you can go to Project--> clean
select your project. It will result clean and build the selected project.